# Get current position from CABasicAnimation in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, animation, position, cabasicanimation

I set a CABasicAnimation toValue und fromValue.

```
let translateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
let targetFrame = CGRectOffset(runnerContentView.frame, targetX, 0);
let sourcePoint = CGPoint(x: startingvalue, y: 0)
translateAnimation.toValue = NSValue(point: targetFrame.origin)
translateAnimation.fromValue = NSValue(point: sourcePoint)
```

I need the *current position from the CABasicAnimation* when i click a Button.

Comment: lookup / access the `presentationLayer`!

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37102573/cashapelayer-detect-touch-during-animation-swift Instead of getting the path property from the presentation layer, you'll want to get the transform.

Comment: @orignaluser2 can u explain it?